# Cash Deposit in bank account

Tags: visas, uk

I received a rejection for my UK visa application. The letter in part says:

> You have stated that you are employed by Al Majal Alarabi Group as an
> Electrical Engineer and that your total monthly income is  SAR (
> https://www1.oanda.com/currency/converter/ as at 26/10/2020). I note
> that you have provided bank statement showing salary payments, however
> this bank statement shows number of additional cash deposits made to
> the account in the last few months. The origin of these funds have not
> been demonstrated and I note that you have declared that you do not
> have any additional income or savings. As such I am not satisfied that
> the statements made in your application form reflect your current
> personal circumstances regarding your employment, occupation or income

Can any body advise me how i can justify this one cash deposit. and what procedure i have to follow???

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  What were the cash deposits?  Do you have any documentation about where they came from?

Comment: Actually one of my friend borrow money from me long time ago and he returns that money .

Comment: I have edited the question to state what I assume you are asking. Please edit if what I wrote is not correct.

Comment: thank you@DJClayworth can you please advise me on this statement ??